# проблема с sass

Tags: sass

скачал node.js,подключил gulp,запускается http://localhost:3000/ ввожу данные в main.sass а у меня ничего не меняется с сайтом и записи не появляются в файле css, что может быть?

Comment: Очевидно не настроен gulp или нет правил watch с файлами sass, нужны данные gulp файла

Comment: // Custom Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
 .pipe(sass({
  outputStyle: 'expanded',
  includePaths: [__dirname + '/node_modules']
 }))
 .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
 .pipe(autoprefixer({
  grid: true,
  overrideBrowserslist: ['last 10 versions']
 }))
 .pipe(cleancss( {level: { 1: { specialComments: 0 } } })) // Optional. Comment out when debugging
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
 .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});

Comment: Отредактируйте свой запрос, или приложите скрин, по спагетекоду невозможно понять, что у вас закоментировано а что работает. Не стоит писать в ответы.